# How to achieve below result set using Mysql Query

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 table and want to get result like below image.
Please help me out on this.

See below two tables

(1) Table: society_block

```
Fields: id,block_name
```

(2) Table: society_flat

```
Fields: id,block_id,flat_no,owner_name
```

**Want to get result like below** 
[image]

### See the Sample data Mysql query Below

```
CREATE TABLE `society_block` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `block_name` tinytext NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `society_block` (`id`, `block_name`) VALUES
(1, 'A'),
(2, 'B'),
(3, 'C');
```

---

```
CREATE TABLE `society_flat` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `block_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `flat_no` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `owner_name` varchar(200) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `society_flat` (`id`, `block_id`, `flat_no`, `owner_name`) VALUES
(1, 1, 101, 'Mahavir'),
(2, 1, 102, 'Pankaj'),
(3, 2, 101, 'Krunal'),
(4, 2, 102, 'Sanjay'),
(7, 1, 103, 'Dipak '),
(9, 2, 103, 'Dipak p'),
(11, 1, 104, 'Pankaj'),
(12, 1, 201, 'Pravin bhai'),
(13, 1, 204, 'mandip'),
(14, 1, 203, 'Banti'),
(16, 2, 104, 'Bhavesh bhai'),
(17, 1, 202, 'Rakesh');
```

---

Comment: Search for ["MySQL pivot"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=MySQL+pivot) or ["MySQL convert records/rows into columns"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=MySQL+convert+records%2Frows+into+columns) on stackoverflow.. This question is a duplicate.

Comment: Can you please give me query for same @RaymondNijland,
and it's not duplicate question .

Answer (score 0):

We can't achieve the output using the single query.

You can use below query for fetching out the flat number wise owner name along with the block id.

SELECT flat_no, GROUP_CONCAT(concat_ws("=>",block_id,owner_name)) FROM `society_flat` group by flat_no order by flat_no

For presentation time, you should have to fetch the blocks and put it up in outer loop and than inside the inner loop execute above query and you can use the column that having block_id and owner_name concat with "=>" and display only those owner name that matching with the outer loop running block_id.

Comment: Thanks, it's help me lot, still looking for any other solution.